# Lines on the right

Tags: pdftex, longtable

I'd like to have vertical lines on the right of my documents (to indicate what the references for that part are). I've tried doing it with a `longtable` containing my whole document (in the left column, and then use the right one to draw the lines) but `pdflatex` doesn't like it if I put a `\section` in the `longtable`. Is there some way to fix this?

Ideally, it's look like that:
[image]

(I need this because I need to be able to recreate most of the document from the sources, and I think having a visual representation of what the sources are would make it easier to remember)

---

Edit: I managed to get something that looks like what I want using `longtable` but the LaTeX code is kinda ugly (mainly because I have to wrap everything in a `minipage` otherwise it doesn't compile).

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\newtheoremstyle{named}{}{}{\itshape}{}{\bfseries}{}{.5em}{#1 #2. (\thmnote{#3})}
\theoremstyle{named}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\title{Colored things}
\maketitle
\begin{longtable}{lllllll}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\section{Red things}\end{minipage} & & \cellcolor{pink} & & & &\\
 & & \cellcolor{pink} & & & &\\
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\subsection{Red balls}\end{minipage} & & \cellcolor{pink} & & & &\\
 & & \cellcolor{pink} & & & &\\
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\begin{definition}[Red ball] Red balls are balls that are red.\end{definition}\end{minipage} & & \cellcolor{pink} & & & &\\
 & & \cellcolor{pink} & & & &\\
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\begin{theorem}Red balls are not blue.\end{theorem}\end{minipage} & & \cellcolor{pink} & & & &\\
 & & \cellcolor{pink} & & & &\\
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\subsection{Red cubes}\end{minipage} & & \cellcolor{pink} & & \cellcolor{orange} & &\\
 & & \cellcolor{pink} & & \cellcolor{orange} & &\\
$\vdots$ & & \cellcolor{pink} & & \cellcolor{orange} & &\\
 & & \cellcolor{pink} & & \cellcolor{orange} & &\\
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\section{Blue things}\end{minipage} & & & & \cellcolor{orange} & &\\
 & & & & \cellcolor{orange} & &\\
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\subsection{Blue cubes}\end{minipage} & & & & \cellcolor{orange} & &\\
 & & & & \cellcolor{orange} & &\\
$\vdots$ & & & & \cellcolor{orange} & &\\
 & & & & \cellcolor{orange} & &\\
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\subsection{Blue pyramids}\end{minipage} & & & & \cellcolor{orange} & &\\
$\vdots$ & & & & \cellcolor{orange} & &\\
 & & & & & &\\
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\section{Green things}\end{minipage} & & & & & &\\
 & & & & & &\\
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\subsection{Green balls}\end{minipage} & & & & & & \cellcolor{yellow}\\
 & & & & & & \cellcolor{yellow}\\
$\vdots$ & & & & & & \cellcolor{yellow}\\
 & & & & & &\\
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}\subsection{Green pyramids}\end{minipage} & & & & \cellcolor{orange} & &\\
 & & & & \cellcolor{orange} & &\\
$\vdots$ & & & & \cellcolor{orange} & &\\
 & & & & \cellcolor{orange} & &\\
\end{longtable}
\section*{References}
[1] Everything about red things, Someone \textcolor{pink}{\rule{0.3cm}{0.3cm}}\newline
[2] Everything about cubes and pyramids, Someone else \textcolor{orange}{\rule{0.3cm}{0.3cm}}\newline
[3] The theory of green balls, Yet another person \textcolor{yellow}{\rule{0.3cm}{0.3cm}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Putting the whole document inside the `longtable` is very wrong. :P

Comment: And are the + and # supposed to be entered by you, or automatic? Are they placeholders? I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: @Alenanno Ideally, they'd be automatic (and I'd just indicate for each section and subsection which references are used). But it doesn't have to be. I would really prefer the lines to be "continuous" (so one long line instead of several small lines lines up with small spaces in between) though.

Comment: @Alenanno : The `+` and `#` are here to represent lines. I'll change it to `|` and `||`.

Comment: you can put `\section` in longtable if that's what you want to do (but you shouldn't want that:-)  the question is to say the least very unclear but framed or mdframed or tcolorbox or changebar probably do something related

Comment: @xavierm02 So let's see: basically the vertical line signals if there is a certain word at the corresponding line, and it continues to appear as long as this condition is met?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle changebar would work if it allowed interleaving, but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: @Alenanno Yes, kind of. I'll tag each section / subsection / definition / theorem with the references where it appears and I want the corresponding lines on the right.

Comment: Maybe `\tcolorbox` does what you want?

Comment: @Johannes_B I couldn't find a function that looked like it would work in the documentation. It would work if I had at most one reference / color at once but in my case, I can have several (for example, the part about red cubes comes from both the book on red things and the book on cubes).

Comment: @Johannes_B Or well it could at least replace the `longtable` I guess, which is already great.

Comment: Off-topic question: Do you just have a handful of references? Where have you seen this style of markup before?

Comment: @Johannes_B Yes, I'll just have a handful of references (so I can have one column per reference). I haven't seen it, I want to do it to visually help remember where to search for things.

Comment: Seems to be much easier to just add a colored sqaure at each section heading, without a complete rule in the margin.

Comment: @Johannes_B I did a really simple example here but for the real thing, there would be references used for one specific theorem / definition and not a whole (sub)(sub)section. And having little squares lets you know for a specific point what the references are but it makes it way harder to memorize the structure of the document.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to draw that colored stripes explicitly, for example like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[absolute, overlay]{textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\markline}[4]{
% #1 -- x position
% #2 -- y position
% #3 -- length of the stripe
% #4 -- color of the stripe
\begin{textblock}{1}(#1,#2)
    \tikz \fill [#4] (0,0) rectangle (0.25,#3);
\end{textblock}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item One
\item Two
\item Three
\item Four
\item Five
\item Six
\item Seven
\item Eight
\item Nine
\item Ten
\end{enumerate}

\markline{6}{2.4}{2}{orange}
\markline{6.25}{2.94}{2}{blue}
\markline{6}{4.02}{3}{orange}
\markline{6.5}{4.6}{6}{green}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, in this form, they will not move automatically if the position of the marked text will be changed.

Comment: Nice answer, +1.  If you change the y coordinate to use a TikZ node based on the enumerate, that would give you a fighting chance of the stripe moving correctly with changing text.